# apigee asXML objects to support colons on xml tag

Tags: xml, apigee

Im using apigee to generate responses that match with the cmis specification. and I have some XML that contains colons. as in

`<atom:title>c9ad76c6-d121-4a32-bb14-e5d43bf91ee6</atom:title>`

obviously the

`var r = response.content.asXML;
r.atom:title = "lala";`

doesn't work, how do I set the content asXML to support colons on tags.

thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 1):

after some reviewing and some help from the apigee team I figure it out. basically you need to define a namespace for atom then define when to use it. like so

```
var r = response.content.asXML;
var atomns = new Namespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/atom");
default xml namespace = atomns;
r["foo"] = "lala";
```

this will generate

```
<xml xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom">
  <atom:foo>lala</atom:foo>
</xml>
```